# Error building program using gcc plugin from linux kernel source tree

Tags: c, gcc, build, linux-kernel, gcc-plugins

I am trying to use a grsecurity gcc plugin that I found on their [unofficial linux kernel source tree](https://github.com/jameshilliard/linux-grsec) (the `respectre_plugin/` one).
My GCC version is 4.7, I modified `scripts/gcc-plugins/Makefile` to make it compile the plugin, and I built it with the root Makefile using `make gcc-plugins`, that shows no error.
Then, when I try to compile a C file that has a Spectre-like flaw, I got the following build error:

`file.c:36:31: error: array_index_mask_nospec is not defined`

This function is defined in `respectre_plugin/respectre_plugin.c`, and I have no idea why I've got this strange build error, if anyone knows about it...
My build invocation is the following:

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -fplugin=/path/to/respectre_plugin.so -c file.c -o file.o`

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Since the problem occurs during the compile step,  it means that the header file for the plug-in was not included.

Comment: `respectre_plugin.c` is converted into a shared object (dynamic library). This is where the function definition (of array_index_mask_nospec) is. That gcc command is unable to locate the `.so` file properly. Usually to utilize any `.so`, you need to provide path to linker and also the name of the `so` with a `-l` option.

Comment: Alright I fixed it,`array_index_mask_nospec` was defined in the linux kernel sources, so I just redefined the symbol in `file.c`. I thought that gcc plugins automatically exported symbols to the source files in order to let the plugin use them